# How to generate HTML reports on Play ScalaTest

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

My intention is to generate a readable HTML test report that would capture my features/scenarios thrown by functional test. I am using `FeatureSpec` for my tests. (I can then show this report to my Product team for their acceptance approval).

I tried the following option on Play console:

```
test-only -h target/html-report MySpecFile
```

This one generated bunch of js & css files but I don't see an html file.

I also tried adding this on my sbt file:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-reports")
```

This only generates a xml file.

Your help is appreciated. I Googled for answers but failed to obtain a working solution so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the ScalaTest dependency and also Pegdown which is used to generate the HTML reports:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.6.0" % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)
```

As [documented](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner), the correct parameter to generate HTML reports is `-h` (`-u` is used to turn on the JUnit XML reporter). So, you can also add the following lines to your `build.sbt` file:

```
testOptions in Test ++= Seq(
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-reports"),
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/test-reports")
)
```

I'm not sure you need both, but of course you can remove `-u` if you want. After that, running `sbt test` will generate a HTML report at `target/test-reports/index.html`. Adding this configuration will enable report generation when using both `test` and `test-only` command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My mistake was that I did not include 'pegdown' dependencies.